# Showing measurement in OpenLayers 6 while modifying

Tags: polygon, javascript, openlayers, measurements, modify-interaction

I have [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/cakcak27/0bgkm2w9/7/).

1. I create class the name  is MeasurementClass. this class used for overlays component creator, setting of html and configure style . this class can handle it.

```js
class MeasurementTooltip {
    constructor(){
        /**
         * The measure tooltip element.
         * @type {HTMLElement}
         */
        this.tooltipElement = null;

        /**
         * Overlay to show the measurement.
         * @type {Overlay}
         */
         this.tooltip = null;

         this.map = null;
    }

    setMap(map){
        this.map = map;
    }

    getElementTooltip(){
        return this.elementTooltip;
    }

    getTooltip(){
        return this.tooltip;
    }

    destroyTooltip(){
        this.tooltipElement = null;
        this.map.removeOverlay(this.tooltip);
    }

    setPosition(coordinate){
        if(this.tooltip instanceof ol.Overlay){
            this.tooltip.setPosition(coordinate);
        }
    }

    createTooltip(){
        if (this.tooltipElement instanceof Element) {
            this.tooltipElement.parentNode.removeChild(measureTooltipElement);
        }
        this.tooltipElement = document.createElement('div');
        this.tooltipElement.className = 'ol-tooltip ol-tooltip-measure';
        this.tooltip = new ol.Overlay({
            element: this.tooltipElement,
            offset: [0, -15],
            positioning: 'bottom-center',
        });
        this.map.addOverlay(this.tooltip);
    }

    showTooltip(obj){
        // let feature = feature;
        let coordinate = null;
        let geometryType = null;
        if(obj.feature instanceof ol.Feature){

            geometryType = obj.type;
            if(geometryType === "Polygon"){
                let polygon = obj.geometry;
                let area = polygon.getArea();
                let luas = thousandFormatID(Math.round(area * 100) / 100) + ' ' + 'm<sup>2</sup>';
                coordinate = polygon.getInteriorPoint().getCoordinates();
                this.tooltipElement.innerHTML = luas;
                this.tooltip.setPosition(coordinate);
            } else if(geometryType == "LineString") {
                let lineString = obj.geometry;
                let length = lineString.getLength();
                let panjangm = thousandFormatID(Math.round(length * 100) / 100) + ' ' + 'm';
                coordinate = obj.coordinate;
                this.tooltipElement.innerHTML = panjangm;
                this.tooltip.setPosition(coordinate);
            }

        }

    }

    renderTooltipElement(textHtml){
        if(this.tooltipElement instanceof Element){
            this.tooltipElement.innerHTML = textHtml;
        }
    }
}
```

2. Next I created the functions that are used to create a tooltip that is added to the object map. a function that is intended as follows:

```js
function measureFeature(props) {
  // let feature = evt.feature;
  let feature = props.feature;
  let action = props.action;
  drawObj.setFeatureId(feature.ol_uid);
  let geometry_id = feature.getGeometry().ol_uid;

  draw_coordinate_length = 0;
  draw_partDistanceOverlay = null;
  draw_totalAreaDistanceOverlay = new MeasurementTooltip();
  draw_totalAreaDistanceOverlay.setMap(map);
  draw_totalAreaDistanceOverlay.createTooltip();
  if (draw_totalAreaDistanceOverlay.tooltip instanceof ol.Overlay) {
    draw_totalAreaDistanceOverlay.tooltip.set('geometry_id', geometry_id);
    if (drawObj.getFeatureId()) {
      draw_totalAreaDistanceOverlay.tooltip.set('feature_id', drawObj.getFeatureId());
    }
  }

  draw_lastPartLineOverlay = new MeasurementTooltip();
  draw_lastPartLineOverlay.setMap(map);
  draw_lastPartLineOverlay.createTooltip();
  if (draw_lastPartLineOverlay.tooltip instanceof ol.Overlay) {
    draw_lastPartLineOverlay.tooltip.set('geometry_id', geometry_id);
    if (drawObj.getFeatureId()) {
      draw_lastPartLineOverlay.tooltip.set('feature_id', drawObj.getFeatureId());
    }
  }
  if (action === "DRAW") {
    feature.getGeometry().on('change', onGeomChange);
  } 
}
```

3. To display the length that will be displayed by the tooltip created earlier in accordance with the geometry made by the Interaction Draw. This function also plays a role in dividing the sides of the polygon so you can find the length of the side, and also contains code to display the polygon area information.

```js
function onGeomChange(e) {
  let geomType = e.target.getType();
  let coordinates = e.target.getCoordinates();
  let geometry_id = e.target.ol_uid;
  if (geomType == "Polygon") {
    coordinates = e.target.getCoordinates()[0];
  }

  if (coordinates.length > draw_coordinate_length) {
    draw_partDistanceOverlay = new MeasurementTooltip();
    draw_partDistanceOverlay.setMap(map);
    draw_partDistanceOverlay.createTooltip();
    if (draw_partDistanceOverlay.tooltip instanceof ol.Overlay) {
      draw_partDistanceOverlay.tooltip.set('geometry_id', geometry_id);
      if (drawObj.getFeatureId()) {
        draw_partDistanceOverlay.tooltip.set('feature_id', drawObj.getFeatureId());
      }
    }

    draw_coordinate_length = coordinates.length;
  } else {
    draw_coordinate_length = coordinates.length;
  }

  let partLine = new ol.geom.LineString([coordinates[draw_coordinate_length - 2], coordinates[draw_coordinate_length - 1]]);

  if (geomType == "Polygon") {
    partLine = new ol.geom.LineString([coordinates[draw_coordinate_length - 3], coordinates[draw_coordinate_length - 2]]);
    calDistance(draw_partDistanceOverlay, partLine.getFlatMidpoint(), partLine.getLength());
  }
  calDistance(draw_partDistanceOverlay, partLine.getFlatMidpoint(), partLine.getLength());


  if (
    geomType == "LineString" &&
    draw_coordinate_length > 2 &&
    e.target.getLength() > new ol.geom.LineString(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]).getLength()
  ) {

    calDistance(draw_totalAreaDistanceOverlay, coordinates[draw_coordinate_length - 1], e.target.getLength());
  }

  if (geomType == "Polygon" && draw_coordinate_length > 3) {
    calArea(draw_totalAreaDistanceOverlay, e.target.getFlatInteriorPoint(), e.target.getArea());
    partLine = new ol.geom.LineString([coordinates[draw_coordinate_length - 2], coordinates[draw_coordinate_length - 1]]);
    calDistance(draw_lastPartLineOverlay, partLine.getFlatMidpoint(), partLine.getLength());
  }
}
```

4. The following functions are used to display the side length or linestring length.

```js
function calDistance(overlay, overlayPosition, distance) {
  overlay.destroyTooltip();
  if (parseInt(distance) == 0) {
    overlay.createTooltip();
    overlay.setPosition([0, 0]);
  } else {
    overlay.createTooltip();
    overlay.setPosition(overlayPosition);
    if (distance >= 1000) {
      let textHtml = (distance / 1000).toFixed(2) + ' km';
      overlay.renderTooltipElement(textHtml);
      if (drawObj.getFeatureId()) {
        overlay.tooltip.set('feature_id', drawObj.getFeatureId());
      }
    } else {
      let textHtml = distance.toFixed(2) + ' m';
      overlay.renderTooltipElement(textHtml);
      if (drawObj.getFeatureId()) {
        overlay.tooltip.set('feature_id', drawObj.getFeatureId());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

5. This is also a function used to display the area.

```js
function calArea(overlay, overLayPosition, area) {
  let textHtml;
  if (parseInt(area) == 0) {

    overlay.setPosition([0, 0]);
  } else {
    overlay.setPosition(overLayPosition);
    if (area > 100000) {
      textHtml = Math.round((area / 1000000) * 100) / 100 + ' km<sup>2<sup>';
      overlay.renderTooltipElement(textHtml);
    } else {
      textHtml = Math.round(area * 100) / 100 + ' m<sup>2<sup>';
      overlay.renderTooltipElement(textHtml);
    }
  }
}
```

6. At the time of running the modifystart I entered the following code

```js
    modify.on('modifystart', function(e) {
      measureFeature({
        action   : "MODIFY",
        feature  : feature,
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

I have a problem like this:

[image]

Why the left side of the overlay that shows the length of the side does not follow the line and does not change like the other sides? Maybe there are some senior colleagues here who can help my problem!

Comment: You are already using a custom style function to highlight the vertices.  You could also use the style function for your calculations and displaying the results as text labels.  That would avoid the need for overlays and listening for geometry changes.

Comment: thanks for the advice. later I will edit the question again. sorry if anything is lacking because I'm still just learning to ask questions on this site